# Длина элемента с классом hidden

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, hidden

Столкнулся с непониманием того, какая высота у элементов с `dislpay: none`;

Приведу пример из работы:

```js
// Button what add slide effect for product characteristics

function hideButtonsMoreCharacteristicsIfWeHaveBitChatacteristics() {

  $(".main-descript-tab__fullTab").each(function(index, el) {
    // var heightField =;
    var innerHeight = el.scrollHeight;
    console.log($(".main-descript-tab").height() + " = heightField");

    if (((el.scrollHeight < $(".main-descript-tab").height()) && (el.scrollHeight !== 0))) {

      // console.log(innerHeight + " = innerHeight");
      $(this).parent(".main-descript-tab").siblings(".main-desc__showMoreInfo").addClass("hidden");
      $(this).parent(".main-descript-tab").css("height", "auto");
    }

  });

}
hideButtonsMoreCharacteristicsIfWeHaveBitChatacteristics();




function switchMainDescription() {
  var mainDescriptionItem = $(".main-desc-title__item"),
    mainDescriptionContent = $(".main-desc__item"),
    active = "active";

  mainDescriptionItem.on("click", function() {
    mainDescriptionItem.removeClass(active);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var index = $('.main-desc-title__item.active').index();

    mainDescriptionContent.removeClass(active);
    mainDescriptionContent.eq(index).addClass(active);

    hideButtonsMoreCharacteristicsIfWeHaveBitChatacteristics();

  });

}
switchMainDescription();







function showMoreCharacteristics() { // Slide effect

  var buttonMoreInformation = $(".main-desc__showMoreInfo"),
    fieldDescriptionActive = "main-descript-tab_active",
    textShowInfo = ".main-desc__showMoreInfo_show",
    textHideInfo = ".main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide";

  buttonMoreInformation.on("click", function() {

    $(this).siblings(".main-descript-tab").toggleClass(fieldDescriptionActive);
    $(this).children(textHideInfo).toggleClass("hidden");
    $(this).children(textShowInfo).toggleClass("hidden");

  })
}
showMoreCharacteristics();





//   FORM Review

var buttonAddComment = $(".code_addReview"),
  formReview = $(".code_formRewiew");

buttonAddComment.on("click", function() {

  $(this).hide();
  formReview.slideDown(600);

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#form-review {
  display: none;
}

.card-main-desc-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.min-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.product-line__title {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.products_related,
.products_looked {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

.good-price {
  display: inline-block;
}

.goods-item-slid .good-price__hist {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.goods-item-slid .good-price__yy,
.goods-item-slid .good-price__nom {
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.goods-item-slid .good-price__hist {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.goods-item-slid .good-price__hist:before {
  bottom: 0.35em;
}

.goods-item-slid__title {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.goods-item-slid__price {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.name-product {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: block;
}

.main-page__product-line {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.goods-item-slid__img {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.goods-item-slid__pic {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.product-line__item {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.product-line__item:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

#cart .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: initial;
}

.list-group {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.list-group a {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-group a:hover {
  color: #ff4e54;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.panel {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.tab-desc {
  display: none;
}

.tab-desc.active {
  display: block;
}

.info-desc-text__item {
  padding: 20px;
}

.descript-tab {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.descript-tab>* {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.descript-tab>*:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-desc-title {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e54;
}

.main-desc-title__item {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 260px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin-right: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-desc-title__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.main-desc-title__item.active {
  background-color: #ff4e54;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-desc__item {
  padding: 20px;
}

.main__card-product {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main__card-product:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.card-product__galery {
  float: left;
}

.main-descript-tab {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 228px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-descript-tab_active {
  height: auto !important;
}

.main-descript-tab p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-descript-tab li {
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 40px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-descript-tab li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.main-descript-tab li span {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 180px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.main-descript-tab li span:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff4e54;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_show {
  margin-left: -18px;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_show:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 6px;
  content: "\f103";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: inherit;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  content: "\f00d";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: inherit;
}

.bl_review {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff4e54;
}

.review_item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff4e54;
}

.review_item__userName {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e54;
  font-family: TahomaBold, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.review_item__time {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.review_item__raiting {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.personal-form-review {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.review_item__fullReview {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.review_product {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 24px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.review_product__title {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.review_product__title__bold {
  font-family: TahomaBold, sans-serif;
}

.bl_raiting__chackbox {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.my_button-review {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff4e54;
}

.my_button-review:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff4e54;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_show {
  margin-left: -18px;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_show:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 6px;
  content: "\f103";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: inherit;
}

.main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  content: "\f00d";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="card-main-desc-wrap">
  <div class="main-desc  tab-wrap">
    <ul class="main-desc-title">
      <li class="main-desc-title__item  tab-title  ">
        Описание
      </li>

      <li class="main-desc-title__item  tab-title active">
        Характеристики
      </li>

      <li class="main-desc-title__item  tab-title ">
        Отзывы
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="main-desc-text">
      <div class="main-desc__item  tab-desc ">
        <div class="wrapperBlock">
          <div class="main-descript-tab ">
            <div class="main-descript-tab__fullTab">


              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quia?</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque doloribus illo impedit modi molestias, recusandae.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quia? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, nulla?</p>

            </div>
          </div>

          <button class="main-desc__showMoreInfo">
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_show">Показать больше информации</span>
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide hidden">Скрыть информацию</span>
                            </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-desc__item  tab-desc active">
        <div class="wrapperBlock">


          <div class="main-descript-tab">
            <ul class="main-descript-tab__fullTab">
              <li>
                <span>Страна производитель:</span>
                <span>Украина</span>
              </li>

              <li>
                <span>Материал</span>
                <span>натуральная кожа</span>
              </li>

              <li>
                <span>Код производителя:</span>
                <span>170550-BM</span>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div>
          <button class="main-desc__showMoreInfo">
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_show">Показать больше информации</span>
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide hidden">Скрыть информацию</span>
                            </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-desc__item  tab-desc " id="tab-review">


        <div class="main-descript-tab">
          <div class="main-descript-tab__fullTab">
            <div id="review" class="hidden">
              <p>У данного товара пока нету отзывов, будь первым
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="review_item">
              <p class="review_item__userName">User Name</p>
              <time class="review_item__time">01.08.2017</time>
              <p class="review_item__raiting"><span>Рейтинг пользователя</span>
                <span>4</span><span>/5</span></p>
              <p class="review_item__fullReview">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A consectetur eos laborum magni quam quod ratione repudiandae suscipit tempora veniam! Aspernatur, atque corporis dignissimos minima nam officia provident quasi quia!</span>
                <span>Alias, amet autem cum cumque delectus, deleniti dignissimos doloribus dolorum facilis illum incidunt iure iusto, laboriosam laborum maxime minus natus necessitatibus perspiciatis quaerat quis repellendus saepe sed similique suscipit unde!</span>
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="main-desc__showMoreInfo">
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_show">Показать больше информации</span>
                                <span class="main-desc__showMoreInfo_hide hidden">Скрыть информацию</span>
                            </button>


        <button class="my_button-review code_addReview">
                                <span class="button_review">Оставить отзыв о товаре</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>



        <form class="form-horizontal personal-form-review code_formRewiew" id="form-review">

          <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Пожалуйста, выберите оценку товара!
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 review_product">
            <p class="review_product__title">Написать отзыв о</p>
            <h2 class="review_product__title review_product__title__bold">Женская сумка Karfei 1710078-04A черная</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group required review_form clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input class="form-control review_name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="*Ваше имя:">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input class="form-control review_email" type="email" name="name" value="" placeholder="Email:">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input class="form-control review_telephone" type="tel" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон:">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="bl_review__raiting">
                <span class="review_text">Оценить товар</span>

                <div class="bl_review__raitingFull">
                  <input class="bl_raiting__chackbox" id="review_star5" type="radio" name="raiting" value="5">
                  <label class="bl_raiting__label" for="review_star5"></label>

                  <input class="bl_raiting__chackbox" id="review_star4" type="radio" name="raiting" value="4">
                  <label class="bl_raiting__label" for="review_star4"></label>

                  <input class="bl_raiting__chackbox" id="review_star3" type="radio" name="raiting" value="3">
                  <label class="bl_raiting__label" for="review_star3"></label>

                  <input class="bl_raiting__chackbox" id="review_star2" type="radio" name="raiting" value="2">
                  <label class="bl_raiting__label" for="review_star2"></label>

                  <input class="bl_raiting__chackbox" id="review_star1" type="radio" name="raiting" value="1">
                  <label class="bl_raiting__label" for="review_star1"></label>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group required">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <textarea class="form-control review_textarea" name="text" rows="5" id="input-review" placeholder="Текст сообщения"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button class="button_lim clearfix" type="button" id="button-review" data-loading-text="Загрузка...">
                                <span class="button_lim__text">Отправить</span>
                            </button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v92g2bdj/1/ Есть 3 переключалки Описание Характеристики и Отзывы. Стоит задача - выводить кнопку Показать больше информации только если контента в данной рубрике наберется >=228px (за это отвечает класс обертка `.main-descript-tab`) Собственно все действие у меня выполняет функция 
`hideButtonsMoreCharacteristicsIfWeHaveBitChatacteristics();` Она срабатывает первый раз при загрузке страници, а второй при клацанье на нужную рубрику.
Собственно баг - Первоначально активирована рубрика Характеристики, и если дальше зайти в Отзывы, то функция отработает правильно. Но если изначально зайти в Описание а потом в Отзывы, то всё ломается (оно выводит кнопку Показать больше информации, хотя контента там столько нету ).

В консоль я вывожу длинны элементов. В первом случае оно отрабатывает верно. Во втором длинны уходят в ноль и функция не отрабатывает. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(".main-descript-tab") возвращает массив.

Попробуйте это:

```
if((( el.scrollHeight <  $(".main-descript-tab").height()) && ( el.scrollHeight !== 0))){
```

Заменить на:

```
if((( el.scrollHeight <=  $(this).parent().height()) && ( el.scrollHeight !== 0))){
```